# Keep app awake after waking up from suspended state

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

AFAIK, iOS only allow app to stay in background mode after waking it in suspended (terminated) state for 10s (3 mins if using `beginBackgroundTask`), I'm having the waking trigger by entering geofence or beacon region, my question is if there are anyway to extend this time block for longer?

Some more info is that I'm also having Background mode location update, and it work very well if I do `startUpdatingLocation` in foreground then goes to background (or wake triggered while app didn't get terminated yet), it can run indefinitely without getting terminated, but not when waking from suspended state.

Comment: you can try claiming that app plays sound in background but then it will not make it to the app store. there is no other way.

Comment: Thanks :( was afraid I have to do some other way